# Drupal: How do I list inside a view all nodes related to a profile node? (not the core profile).

Tags: drupal, view, arguments, cck, relationships

How do I list inside a view (block or page) all nodes related to a profile node?

The relation between nodes is because Node A has a cck field with a number, that is the node number of the profile.

When I mean "profile" I mean the content profile, (wich is a node, and not the core profile).

I´ve tried with relations and arguments, but as the relation is because of that cck field, it seems that´s not possible...?

Thanks for your help !!!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thing you are created the view with the base type user. please change the type to node. So you can access all the content_profile field from the views.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I do have the view type:node already, the thing is that no matter what I put it, I don´t know how to manage the relationship with the special cck field. It would be easier if I want to relate a node to a user profile, but I need to relate it to a node profile (it has to match the node number of the profile, with the numder that the cck field has).